# Proxy settings blocking podcasts, YouTube, Skype

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, proxy

I am living in a university dormitory where I have to set up proxy settings in order to access to internet.

On my laptop, I can use the Internet as normal, no problem at all.

I use Connectify to convert my laptop into a wireless router/network so that I can use wireless on my iPhone.

However, the problems are:
- Every time I try to watch podcasts and YouTube, `it says: the server is not correctly configured.`
- Every time I try to access to Skype, it does not work (Skype said the problem is due to proxy settings)
- Every time I can not use MobileVOIP.

ALL the problems are due to the proxy settings.

Do you expert have any solutions?

Please do not recommend to buy a new internet line or use cellphone edge (3G).

Answer (score 1):

You need to find an open proxy that isn't blocked by your University, or buy a VPN/VPS/ssh-shell to another network.  Your University won't be proxying SSL port 443 because that breaks any commercial transactions that happen over that port.